# Select Row or Column of checkboxes from matrix using javascript

Tags: javascript

As the title states I was wondering how i could perform the task of selecting a whole row/column of checkboxes using javascript as i have already done it with a foreach but that takes 3 seconds i wish that i can make this less.

```
 1 2 3 4 5  select start end  
1                            Button 
2  
3  
4  
5  
select
```

Im not sure how to depict it exactly i hope that this can better explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css classes to designate the rows and columns for each checkbox, and then use jQuery to get the row or column of interest, like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLqh8/).

In the example, `$('.r2')` gets all checkboxes with the class 'r2' (ie., in row 2) ... change it to `$('.c3')` to get all in column 3.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NLqh8/1/) is an example of creating a button to check a row or column.

UPDATE: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/WSPXQ/) is a more dynamic example

Comment: Thanks I've been playing around with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xacXy/9/) and it seems to work well

Comment: Is there a way to make it more dynamic though? Since i was generating the check-boxes at run-time would it also be possible to make the JavaScript command created at run-time.

Comment: For some reason when im testing the code from [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xacXy/10/) in my telerik app it isn't paying attention to the JavaScript

Comment: It seems that this is dependent on class which is a problem as i already had a template dam i don't know how i can apply it now.

Comment: Are you including the jquery code in your application? Also, why will having a template prevent you from using classes? Can't you add the classes to the checkboxes?

Comment: But its insane to add that many classes since i have a matrix which is dynamic up to 50y and 25x did you check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xacXy/10/)

Comment: I did check your fiddle. I don't really understand your reservation with adding the classes, tho... it is just a convenient way to add multiple markers to an input element. Feel free to try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/WSPXQ/) instead, to see how it works with dynamic dimensions."

Comment: Hi Mike im sorry the reason i find it annoying is that my css code isnt working .r1
        {
            background-image: url('CheckBoxSprites.gif');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: transparent;
            background-position: 0px 0px 
        }
        .c1
        {
            background-image: url('CheckBoxSprites.gif');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: transparent;
            background-position: 0px 0px; 
        } otherwise i wouldnt mind the classes do you have any idea why it could not be working?

Comment: I wouldn't use these classes for actual styling, because then you need to define a style for every input. Especially since it looks like you are just defining a background for all checkboxes to share. I would probably put `input[type=checkbox] { background-image: url('CheckBoxSprites.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: transparent; background-position: 0px 0px }` in my stylesheet file. The styles like c1, r2 etc should not be defined from a styling perspective. As I said previously, they are just markers.

Comment: Well I've seen it it done i just can't understand why mine isn't working in this manner.I really wish somebody could explain how to properly do this.

Comment: You might want to post another question specific to your CSS issue.

Comment: I was thinking in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mNDWg/) it would probably be better to use a table rather than divs what do you think

Comment: I agree. If you want it to look tabular, use `<table>` :-)

Comment: Can you tell me if you see anything wrong with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/832XB/)

Comment: At line 42 or so, you have `else if (i == rows + 1)(` instead of `else if (i == rows + 1){` (you should have an opening curly brace instead of a paren)

Comment: That kinda solved a bit of the problem now i have to see why the design isn't right

Comment: But there is also another problem when i posted it to jquery they said that it has to be done like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/832XB/11/) For some reason in the fiddle it doesn't show up but they said jquery only accepts valid html meaning that once a tag is opened it has to be closed in the same instance thus use a string and then looped for click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

check out jQuery's .each function it would make that task piece of cake :)

Let me know if you need assistnace with it.

Comment: Could you explain beforehand as i saw javascript examples but they where only able to select a column or row both were not functional for both cases.